# C++ array comparison and move? Why does the apple not move?

Tags: c++, arrays, compare

```
void moveApple(char gr[][SIZEX], int sp[], int keyMove[], int apple[][COUNT]) {
for(int i(0); i < COUNT; i++) { 
    if (( apple[0][COUNT] < (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (apple[1][COUNT] < (sp[1] + keyMove[1])))
    {
        apple[0][0] += (sp[0] + keyMove[0]);
    }
```

This is a procedure from a project I am working on... the apple should move based on the position of sp (which is a spark array, for a variable that moves), I want the apple to move towards sp with each of sp's moves. Below is another attempt that also does not work:

```
void moveApple(char gr[][SIZEX], int sp[], int keyMove[], int apple[][COUNT]) {
for(int i(0); i < COUNT; i++) { 
    if (( apple[0][COUNT] < (sp[0] + keyMove[0])) && (apple[1][COUNT] < (sp[1] + keyMove[1])))
    {
        gr[apple[0][-1]][apple[1][-1]] = APPLE;
    }
```

Comment: I think your main misunderstanding here is that array indexes are absolute, they aren't relative. An array starts at 0, you never use index -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you cant do that: apple[0][-1];
also dont you want apple[1][COUNT-1]?
more info on each array's purpose could help

Comment: Basically, the apple follows the spark array around a set grid (gr). The 'keymove' is what the user enters and where the spark will move. The apple wants to move towards the spark.The if statement should make sure the apple only moves in a direction based on the movement of the spark. There are four apples altogether, but only one spark. I will try count -1.

Comment: what is spark? what are the rules of movement? where is 'spark' located? who controls the spark and who the apple(s)?

Comment: spark is a user controlled object if you like, sort of like pacman. The user can move up, down, left or right but will get stuck at walls. Spark is placed randomly around the grid to begin with. The user moves spark, but the apples follow spark automatically using the procedure stated. However, the if only account for one particular movement scenario. Hope this helps

Comment: So what is the problem, what is supposed to happen and isnt? and please state on which move direction were dealing with.

Comment: the apple is supposed to move one grid space closer to spark. The direction I was hoping for was a south west direction, what I was hoping was [-1][-1]

Comment: didnt you say the apple can only move one direction at a time?

Comment: The apple can only move 1 space at a time, sorry. It can move in any direction though, but only one space per move.

Comment: you need to know where the apple is and move his coords receptively to what you want.  
why having two gridlines? can the apple go off limits of the board?

Comment: no, the apple must stay on the grid. Two gridlines... for the apple? I have the grid which is a square shape, but I'm not sure what that means. I think the coord changing is the bit i'm messing up

Comment: if all the pieces are on the board all the time, why having two boards denoters? hold just one and use polymorphism.

Comment: sorry but not OOP, I thought you needed that for polymorphism. Although, not too sure what you mean about two board denoters?

Comment: to make it simple: imagine this: you have the board, each cell holds two ints that provide the coords and another variable(enum is good) that tells you if an apple is on the cell, or the spark, or nothing.
  
now all you need to do is to find out where the spark is and move across the board and move the apples. thats the easiest way.

Comment: that sounds great, but what does enum do? Also, how would you actually move the apples since the user does not control them like spark?

Comment: just use an int then, decide that 0 means nothing, 1 apple, 2 spark.
you do not move them, you simply change the flag that tells whats on the cell.

Comment: ok, I get the int part then, thanks. However, what is the 'flag', and how would I change it?

Comment: you want each cell to tell you its coords and what is on it, the flag is the thing that tells you whats on it, here you chose to use int.

Comment: how would I set the int to recognise 0 as apple, 1 as spark, etc.?

Comment: I have tried to do this, will it work: ` int flag;
 for(int i(0); i < SIZEY; i++)
 {
  for(int j(0); j < SIZEX; j++)
  {
   if (flag == 0)
   {`